# PDO Statement returning false

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am running 2 queries, the first one goes through correctly and returns the desired value, but the second one returns false.

I have set `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` so I should be getting an exception over false, so I am guessing that my `$stmt->execute();` is the culprit here.

As that's the only function that can return false now that I've set the error attribute.
I have also tried setting `$stmt->closeCursor();`, `$stmt = null;`, and `unset($stmt);` with no avail.

This executes two queries (both "darkrp" and "pointshop" in the `fetch_wallet()` function.

```
if($this->pdo) {
    foreach($this->methods as $method => $bool) {
        if($bool) { $array[$method] = $this->fetch_wallet($method); }
    }
}
```

This is the `fetch_wallet()` function:

```
public function fetch_wallet($type) {
    if($type == "darkrp") {
        $query = "SELECT `wallet` FROM `darkrp_player` WHERE uid=:uid LIMIT 1";
    }
    elseif ($type == "pointshop") {
        $query = "SELECT `points` FROM `pointshop_data` WHERE uniqueid=:uid LIMIT 1";
    }
    try {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $this->uniqueid));
        $result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        return $result;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

When I run `var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());` I get this, which means that both queries runs fine, although the last one returns false when it should return **440**. No exception is thrown.

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(5) "00000"
  [1]=> NULL
  [2]=> NULL
}
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(5) "00000"
  [1]=> NULL
  [2]=> NULL
}
```

Printed screen of the pointshop_data table in phpMyAdmin (I want the 440 value there):

[image: Screenshot]

Value returned from `var_dump($this->uniqueid);` is **3266928646**

I have debugged everything, and I get no errors whatsoever, just a false.

**PHP Version:** 5.3.10

**MySQL Version:** 5.5.38

**OS:** Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: if execute returns false it probably means that no rows were found. verify that your db contains a row for `$this->uniqueid`

Comment: I have verified the query in phpMyAdmin and it returns fine when replacing `:uid` with the actual unique ID.

Comment: Add more echo/var_dump statements at various places to check

Comment: @hjpotter92 There's nothing more I can check. I've already dumped everything that has to do with the PDO connection and the statements and according to the dumped data, everything is in order. I can't find any errors anywhere in the script.

Comment: What are the outputs for `var_dump($stmt)` right before you use `execute()` call?

Comment: object(PDOStatement)#7 (1) {
["queryString"]=>
string(61) "SELECT `wallet` FROM `darkrp_player` WHERE `uid`=:uid LIMIT 1"
}
object(PDOStatement)#7 (1) {
["queryString"]=>
string(67) "SELECT `points` FROM `pointshop_data` WHERE `uniqueid`=:uid LIMIT 1"
} Doesn't tell me much

Comment: Are you always querying the same table? The code shows two different tables.

Comment: Yeah, I'm querying two different tables that reside in the same database. They use the same parameter though

Comment: Can we see output of `print_r($this->methods);` right before your foreach?

Comment: Array
(
 [darkrp] => 1
 [pointshop] => 1
) That's weird. They should be true instead of 1, it's set in a [config file](http://svenskunganka.com/share/2014-08-11_07-33-59.png).

Comment: Could you also check the `darkrp_player` table then?

Comment: The `darkrp_player` table returns the value I want, here's a [screenshot](http://svenskunganka.com/share/2014-08-11_07-37-54.png) of what the row I fetch looks like.

Comment: It can be worth mentioning that I rewrote this from MySQLi to PDO because this code I used to have just randomly stopped working for some reason, [GitHub](https://github.com/Svenskunganka/OpenLoad/blob/master/src/core/openload.class.php#L143-L163)

Comment: Give me a few. I'll load up the IDE and recreate

Comment: Can you post both your table screenshots or create table?

Comment: [Here's the SQL](http://svenskunganka.com/share/db.sql) I currently use.

Comment: My guess is that there is an error with the query. An error with the query sometimes doesn't trigger an error with PDO/MySQL. Try logging the query and bound vars to a file to see what is happening.

Comment: @Svenskunganka you use bigint(20) in one case and varchar(30) in another. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Svenskunganka And your connection page? I'd prefer not to retype. just so I can re-create your exact code (with your indentations/style)

Comment: Can you push the PDO code in a separate branch on github?

Comment: you should at least check the response value of `$stmt->execute()`

Comment: @JimiDini This project is a framework for other tools, I have no control over how they setup their databases. DarkRP is a mod for a game and [Pointshop](https://github.com/adamdburton/pointshop-mysql/blob/master/pointshop.sql) is a "plugin" for the same game, each made by different people. @Daryl Gill I'll make another branch on GitHub for you. @hjpotter92 will do! @Raptor response is `false`

Comment: [Here's the new branch on GitHub](https://github.com/Svenskunganka/OpenLoad/tree/dev)

Comment: @Svenskunganka Since the response for `execute` is false, you DO have an error somewhere.

Comment: If the response is `false`, it means that your SQL fails to execute. This explains why `fetchColumn()` returns `false`, as there is no more rows to return.

Comment: @Raptor Yeah that's what I'm trying to figure out. For the record, those of you who wants to test this out, you need to execute a JS function from your console. [Use this function](http://svenskunganka.com/share/2014-08-11_08-26-09.txt) to do that and the back-end will execute, returning JSON data.

Comment: Try to cast number to string (or do explicit typed bind)

Comment: @techouse What do you mean with scalar value? I'm not familliar with that term.

Comment: @JimiDini by default PDO binds everything as a string, unless you explicitly state otherwise.

Comment: @Svenskunganka Emm, well are you sure that it's not `null` or an array or an object, in other words a value that can't be bound successfully.

Comment: @techouse As it's working for the first query, it is able to bind successfully. The variable is not being changed between the queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there must be some other error in your class that makes this code does not work.

I've imported your tables structure and created the following testing code:

```
<?php

class A
{
    private $pdo;
    private $uniqueid;
    private $methods = ['darkrp' => true, 'pointshop' => true];

    public function __construct($pdo, $uniqueid)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
        $this->uniqueid = $uniqueid;

    }


    public function fetch_wallet($type)
    {
        if ($type == "darkrp") {
            $query = "SELECT `wallet` FROM `darkrp_player` WHERE uid=:uid LIMIT 1";
        } elseif ($type == "pointshop") {
            $query = "SELECT `points` FROM `pointshop_data` WHERE uniqueid=:uid LIMIT 1";
        }
        try {
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $this->uniqueid));
            $result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
            return $result;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }


    public function run()
    {


        if ($this->pdo) {
            foreach ($this->methods as $method => $bool) {
                if ($bool) {
                    $array[$method] = $this->fetch_wallet($method);
                    var_dump($array[$method]);
                }
            }
        }

    }


}


$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tests', 'root', '');

$a = new A($pdo, 3266928646);

$a->run();
```

The result I get for this is:

```
string(4) "2075" string(3) "440"
```

So it is working as it should.

Please try this code (that's the whole file - of course you need to change your db name, user and password) and check if it gets you the same results. If yes, probably you have other errors in your class.

Comment: I was going to suggest to convert the varchar in one database to match the other which is using bigint. This will keep data continunity, and also recommend pointing towards using integer validations instead of string validations (if necessary using `===`) But yeah, what you've done sums it all up in one

Comment: This is indeed [working](http://svenskunganka.com/demo/openload/test.php). I am stumped, I have absolutely no clue why this works, while my class is breaking it. @DarylGill I can't really change the database schemas as they're controlled by the authors of [DarkRP](https://github.com/FPtje/DarkRP) and [Pointshop](https://github.com/adamdburton/pointshop)

Comment: @Svenskunganka In above example I haven't changed database schema. It is exactly the same as yours and it's working without a problem. Try to put this kind of code to your project and run it as this one works in single file. Maybe your data isn't set the same or something is being changed between running function.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek The [make_ids()](https://github.com/Svenskunganka/OpenLoad/blob/dev/src/core/openload.class.php#L130-L136) function is generating the UniqueID out of another ID, but as it works for the `darkrp_player` table, it is really odd that it isn't working for the `pointshop_data` table. Here's a [live demo](http://svenskunganka.com/demo/openload/index.php?template=soil) of the whole project. Execute the function [from here](http://svenskunganka.com/share/2014-08-11_08-26-09.txt) in your console and you'll get a JSON result back. (That JS function is executed automatically by the game)

Comment: Hit *Enter* to mute the music on that live demo site by the way.

Comment: What can be the error in my class that causes this? I'm looking through it but I can't find any error anywhere. Although my former MySQLi code stopped working after [this commit](https://github.com/Svenskunganka/OpenLoad/commit/24e79aabf93a413a416291187602c9be22edbb69) (I think)

Comment: @Svenskunganka I don't see any error when looking at this code. But in config you have now for example `$db_data = false;` so probably you changed some code for testing (?). I'm afraid it will be really hard anyone to tell where the problem is because the code you asked about as you see above is working fine.

Comment: I'm guessing this is the furthest Stackoverflow can take me, thank you guys for your help! Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -6):

Change

`$stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $this->uniqueid));`

to

```
$stmt->bindValue(':uid', $this->uniqueid);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) `PDOStatement::execute` accepts an associative array.